# Jenkins : pipeline error - cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a pipeline on jenkins (Centos server) and trying a run selenium test (command: mvn clean install) but during the build phase on jenkin the following error is displayed:

```
Running mu.automate.TestCaseService
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 106.0.5249.21 (71f4e2c9a6f38f5550a8ea29a984a08304554956-refs/branch-heads/5249@{#228}) on port 40216
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 1.243 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   setUp(dummy.automate.TestCaseService): Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  tearDown(dummy.automate.TestCaseService)

Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

I have downloaded the latest driver from the link below:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

I have added the driver on the path as follows on  my centos server where jenkins is installed:

```
/opt/chromedriver
```

Then in the code for the driver to load in the test is as follows:

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "/opt/chromedriver");
```

Based on the online resource it looks like an incompatibility issue between the driver and the  browser but I don't how how to check it.

Can anyone point me out what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the issue by installing chrome on my Centos. Please find link below for installation:

[link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-google-chrome-on-redhat-rhel-fedora-centos-linux/)

Posted it just in case someone else come across this issue.